Does MAUI have a built-in notification window to rate the application in Google Play?
Does maui have a built-in app rating popup window like the one in the image below?

Currently I am doing something like this:
string packageName = "com.<valu>.<valu>";
string playStoreUrl = $"market://details?id={packageName}";
var opened = await Launcher.OpenAsync(playStoreUrl);
if (opened)
{
    Preferences.Set("Rated", true);
}

But in this way, I do not check whether the user has actually already rated the app, and instead of displaying him the window for rating it takes him to the google play app.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/StoreReviewPlugin


But in this way, I do not check whether the user has actually already
rated the app, and instead of displaying him the window for rating it
takes him to the google play app.

You should be careful about how and when you ask users to rate your app, there may be penalties from stores. As for advice, you can use a counter on the app start and storage that count, then when the counter reaches a specific number, display a dialogue asking the users if they want to rate the app, if they decline the offer, reset the counter to ask them later, also leave the option to do it themselves.
For more details, you can refer to Usage and the AppRatingSample for a fully detailed implementation.
